# Drupal form submission

Tags: drupal, drupal-forms

I have created a form in drupal. I don't know how to handle the submission. I want to do some selection from database with the values i get from form. Here is my code to create form

```
    function q_search_form() {
$form['qsearch']['category'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array(0 => 'Any', 1 => 'Automotive', 2 => 'Real Estate'),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => 'drop-box'),
    '#prefix' => '<table width="470"><tr><td width="170">Select Category</td><td width="300">',
    '#suffix' => '</td></tr>'
);
$form['qsearch']['city'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array(0 => 'Any', 1 => 'Calicut', 2 => 'Kochi'),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => 'drop-box'),
    '#prefix' => '<tr><td width="170">City</td><td width="300">',
    '#suffix' => '</td></tr>'
);
$form['qsearch']['property'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array(0 => 'Any', 1 => 'House', 2 => 'Land'),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => 'drop-box'),
    '#prefix' => '<tr><td width="170">Property</td><td width="300">',
    '#suffix' => '</td></tr>'
);
$form['qsearch']['wanto'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#options' => array(0 => 'Any', 1 => 'Sell', 2 => 'Buy'),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => 'drop-box'),
    '#prefix' => '<tr><td width="170">Want to</td><td width="300">',
    '#suffix' => '</td></tr>'
);
$form['qsearch']['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Search'),
    '#attributes' => array('id' => 'Search', 'class' => 'srch-button'),
    '#prefix' => '<tr><td><a class="adv-srch" href="#">Advance Search</a></td><td>',
    '#suffix' => '</td></tr></table>'
);
return $form;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple. You just have to implement the `form_submit` function. From the function above, I assume the name of your module to be `q_search`. So, here is what the submit function would look like:

```
function q_search_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // you can get the values submitted by the users using
  // `$form_state['values']`, and use the database functions
  // to implement your logic.
}
```

If you also want to validate the user inputs before the actual submit, you should add a validation function which would look like:

```
function q_search_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  // validate here
}
```

You can use [form_set_error](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7), in the validate function if the validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can write following submit function,

```
function q_search_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // To get selected values from form
  $values = $form_state['values'];
  // do print_r($values); exit; to check the values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do pretty much anything you want in the `form_submit` function.

```
function q_search_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $category = $form_state['values']['category'];
  $city = $form_state['values']['city'];
  //etc..

  //use these values to query your database tables
  $query = db_select($category, 'c');
  //narrow results to those only in the selected city:
  $query->join($city, 'cy', 'c.city = cy.cid');
  //narrow results further with more ->join statements
  $results = $query
    ->fields('c', array(fields you want from the categories table))
    //fields from other tables...
    ->execute();

  //do whatever with the $results (print on a different page, print in a table, etc).
```