# handling submission with a "Form Maker"-created form

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-7

I'm using Drupal 7 and HAVE to use the Form Maker (https://drupal.org/project/drupal-form) module. Since it's not a normal form, I don't know how to do something like hooking as  [Drupal form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16732010/drupal-form-submission) Q/A explains for normal forms.

The available options for "action after submission" for those in-database forms are:

1. Stay on form.
2. Link to an article.
3. Display custom text.
4. Redirect to an URL.

Is there any way I can handle the form submission? e.g.: Is there a way to reference the form state for the submitted form in the url I specify if using (e.g.) option 4? (or whatever mechanism exists to recover that data by knowing+referencing the submitted record).

BTW I'm a total drupal n00b, and couldnt Find TFM to R (so I can follow the RTM principle) about that special issue in the Form Maker doc.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this module still uses the form API, so you should just be able to use [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to modify these forms.  I'm sure there's some kind of naming convention for the IDs of these forms, which will allow you to apply changes exclusively to form maker forms.

If you need to customize the handling of form submissions, you can include your own submit handler by using the [#submit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#submit_property) form attribute.  Note: the example in the link adds the submit handler to a field in the form, but in most cases I add the submit handler to the form array itself. (i.e. `$form['#submit'] = array("submit_callback")`)

**Edit in response to comments**

You do not need to reference a form_id when invoking hook_form_alter().  Instead, you can invoke it globally, which will cause drupal to call your hook on every form.  As you can see from the documentation link I provided, the `$form_id` is passed to the function, and you can use that to conditionally modify the form.  Please look at the comments on the documentation page for usage examples.

Unless these forms are being embedded using a third party service, if this module is actually legitimate it will be hooking its forms through the form API.  Implement hook_form_alter(), and print off the form_id's that are passed to the function.  Go to a page that has one of this forms on it, and see what gets printed.

(Also, [form_id]_form_alter() is not the correct syntax for invoking this hook on specific forms.  Should be hook_form_[form_id]_alter(), where hook is your module name.)

Comment: As I search in database, I can't find an id like you say (i.e. a naming convention), but two numerical ids (one for database table `form_maker_table`, one for node id). So i can't do <id>_form_alter() nor <id>_form_submit() in that way, since they would be 88_form_alter() and 88_form_submit().

Comment: BTW the form hooks http://drupalcode.org/project/drupal-form.git/blob/2db2b50b916abfc66ce375f8edd5214aef155b4b:/form_maker.module << here, are for editing the forms in the admin panel (i.e. designing a form), but not handlers for the sent forms.

Comment: found the entry point: it doesn't seem to be a "legitimate" form, in the sense of allowing such hooks.